# Create/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile - can clients use their PPal Accounts

Tags: paypal

I have looked around SO for this but I can't seem to find anything like it.

On my service, I wish to charge on a per-month basis depending on how many users my clients have.

So this question is split up into two parts.

1. What I want to know is it possible for a client to use their own paypal account (without entering any CC details) with conjunction with **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile** via the **NVP**, I have looked through the documentation and can not discern anything. So clearly it is not possible to do it via NPV - From what I've seen so far.

   i. If I do an Express-Checkout Subscription, I can do 20% change on total amount every 180 days (**I DO NOT** want to do this) - I want to be able to get the Profile via the IPN and then modify the monthly amount on as-need basis

   ii. There was some mention of Referenced Transactions, but the Documentation is very confusing.
2. So say there is a way to create a recurring payment subscription via a PayPal Account on the PayPal website, next step is to be able to update the Subscription via **UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile** NVP command.

While I am happy to pass on CC details (which already works great), I am just wondering if it is indeed possible create a button, which would create a Subscription - once on success an IPN request is sent back with the ProfileID which I can modify the Billing Amount by NVP.

So TL;DR;

The current flow I have

1. Register on our website
2. Enter CC Details
3. Backend submits the data to PayPal and if passed - continues on.
4. On any Account modifications, update Profile Monthly Amount Automatically.

The flow I want

1. Register on website
2. Click on an Authorize Button Redirected to PayPal
3. Login to their PayPal Account Create Recurring Profile.
4. On any Account modifications, update that Profile Monthly Amount Automatically.

*edit to add* - this is all working now, had to contact and harass PayPal directly for a lonngg time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused because it sounds like you answered your own question, but then said that's not what you want..??

Express Checkout does exactly what you outlined at the end of your post, and it triggers an IPN just like any other PayPal transaction.  You are indeed limited on how much you can adjust the amounts of profiles created with EC, though, just like you mentioned with the 20% every 180 days.  If you create profiles with Payments Pro (DoDirectPayment or PayFlow) then you're not limited and you can adjust the amounts however much you need to whenever you need to.

Reference Transactions and Preapprovals may be something to look into as well.  I actually wrote [an article about what they are and how they differ from each other](http://go.developer.ebay.com/content/choosing-right-paypal-product-your-application-little-planning-goes-long-way) awhile back that you might be interested in.

Comment: I wasn't too sure how to word it. What I want to be able to do is to provide the option to use PayPal accounts by re-directing to their website, the current flow just asks for CC details then does a NVP command - keeping it on my website, where as I want it to go onto the PayPal Website so they can use a PayPal account - not just purely enter in CC details (but without the 20% limitation per month) - if it isn't possible, it's not a big loss as the current system works as-is, I just wanted to be able to provide more options. Nice article btw

Comment: Ok, well yeah, what you have now would simply be the credit card option you're giving people who may not have PayPal.  The PayPal option, for those that want it, would be done with Express Checkout, but you would indeed be limited to the 20% increase.  If you need more than that you could always kill the current subscription and create a new one for the person.

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification, I don't think killing the subscription will work; seems like too much of a hassle - I am mainly dealing with Business's. They  get charged on a per-user limit (so if they add more users, they will automatically get charged extra per month - which can be larger than 20% increments); I guess "Don't fix what isn't broken" applies here. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Reference transactions would work, but you'd basically be building your own recurring payments system utilizing them as opposed to setting up recurring profiles for people in the PayPal platform.